# An efficient algorithm for deciding which vertices are in a given set of triangles

Tags: geometry, algorithms

> Consider two arrays $P = [p_1,\ldots,p_n]$ and $T = [t_1,\ldots,t_m]$, where the $p_i$ and $t_i$ describe points in the plane given by $x,y$-coordinates. Find an efficient algorithm that determines for each point $p_i$ whether it is contained in a triangle spanned by ***SOME*** points in $T$ or not. (We can assume that all points are in general position, meaning that no three points lie on a straight line.)

If I am not mistaken it suffices to compute the convex hull $C$ of the points of $T$, which can be done in $\mathcal{O}(m \log(m))$-time and test for each $p_i$ whether it is inside $C$ or not, which can be done in $\mathcal{O}(nm)$ time. (Here I used the fact that every convex polygon can be triangulated.)

So all in all we have a runtime of $\mathcal{O}(m \log(m) + nm)$. Is this a sufficient solution or can this be improved?

Comment: You need to define "efficient". Since you have two parameters, $m$ and $n$, what's efficient may depend on which regime of the parameter space you're interested in. If $n\sim m$, then $\mathcal{O}(m \log(m))$ is negligible compared to $\mathcal{O}(nm)$, and I suspect you can't do better than $\mathcal{O}(nm)$ (though I'm not sure).

Comment: But if $n\ll\log m$, then $\mathcal{O}(nm)$ is negligible compared to $\mathcal{O}(m \log(m))$. In that case, you can compute for each $p_i$ the angles at which the $t_i$ lie around it and figure out in $\mathcal{O}(m)$ time whether they all lie on one side, so that gives you $\mathcal{O}(nm)$ without the $\mathcal{O}(m \log(m))$ cost of the convex hull.

Comment: Then again, $\mathcal{O}(nm)$ is the worst-case complexity. Maybe you are more interested in the average case, and maybe you have a reason to believe that the convex hull is (on average) much smaller than $m$; then it is an entirely different story.